# Limit of several variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

What would be the limit of the given multi-variable functions?

$$1. \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} x \cdot sin \left(\frac{1}{y}\right)$$
$$2. \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,1)} \frac{e^{x}-y}{xy}$$

I tried to solve with x=0 and y=0 but in this this method didn't work. Is there any other way??

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Taylor expansions of the functions?

Comment: hhhmm... that might work.. i will look at it...

Answer (score 1):

For 
$$1. \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} x \cdot sin \left(\frac{1}{y}\right)$$,
$ |x\sin\frac{1}{y}|\leq |x|\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For 
$$2. \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{e^{x}-y}{xy}$$
The limit does not exist. Take for example $(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$ and $(\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$  and get that their limits are $+\infty$ and $-\infty$

Comment: i mistyped before.. sorry for that but y $\rightarrow$ 1

Answer (score 1):

By applying  the taylor expansion of $e^x=1+x+x^2/2+...$, we have $\frac{e^x-y}{xy}=\frac{1+x+x^2/2+...-y}{xy}$ which has the same limit as $\frac{x}{xy}$, namely $1$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow 0$.  The limit is 1.